# Firewall incoming packets are dropped with VLAN configuration

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, vlan

In my Windows PC, installed `scapy` tool for sending packets from my system to raspberry Pi board connected to my machine using VLAN.

In my raspberry Pi board, Firewall rules are already configured and one such rule is as below

```
Chain VARIABLE_IN
0     0 ACCEPT udp  --  eth0.61 * 229.255.41.90 160.48.249.97 udp spt:1125 dpts:3490:1125
```

Using scapy, below command is executed to send packets

```
p=Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/Dot1Q(vlan=61)/IP(src='229.255.41.90',dst='160.48.249.97')/UDP(sport=1125, dport=1125)/"hello123"
sendp(p,iface='Ethernet')
```

After executing above commands, packets are not updated in firewall rule.

But in firewall rule if source ip is changed to 160.48.249.90 like below

```
Chain VARIABLE_IN
    0     0 ACCEPT udp  --  eth0.61 * 160.48.249.90 160.48.249.97 udp spt:1125 dpts:3490:1125
```

and scapy command as below

```
p=Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/Dot1Q(vlan=61)/IP(src='160.48.249.90',dst='160.48.249.97')/UDP(sport=1125, dport=1125)/"hello123"
    sendp(p,iface='Ethernet')
```

Now packets are updated. What is the connection between VLAN eth0.61 and source ip address?
If i check `ipconfig` in my board, then it shows as below:

```
eth0.61: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  metric 1
        inet 160.48.219.91  netmask 255.255.255.128  broadcast 160.48.249.127
        inet6 fd80::212:22jf:ff33:4565  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
```

So IP address range starting from 160 series is only supported by eth0.68?

Comment: You can't use a multicast address as source address.

Comment: My board ip is 160.48.219.91. And when i check `iproute` it daisplays `229.255.41.90 dev eth0.61 scope link  src 160.48.249.97`. So as per this destination ip is `229.255.41.90` and multicast ip can be destination ip, right ?

Comment: Yes, multicast can be the destination if the recipient is listening for it. However, your example had `src='229.255.41.90'` which implies it is the source IP

Comment: Got it, Thanks. In the  board `229.255.41.90` was considered as destination IP. But in my testing using scapy, passed this IP as source IP, hence it was not working.